# Drawing many circles that all meet at the origin, like a spiral using turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have just started learning Turtle, and want to make a circular rosette formed from 45 circles (repeats every 8 degrees), where each has a radius 50 and is joined at the origin.

**Example desired output**:
[image]

I have some code, but it only makes a single circle:

```
from turtle import *
from math import *
def spiral():
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(0,50)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.color("orange")
    times_crossed_y >= 0

    for n in range(45):
        setposition((8*n,-8*n))
        x_sign = 1.0
        while times_crossed_y >= 45:
            turtle.foward(2*math.pi*50/360.0)
            turtle.right(1.0)
        return
circle(100)
print('finished')
bye()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please do not encourage `import *` as it makes it difficult to immediately determine the origin of a function; consider `import x as y` instead.

Comment: @ti7 I've only seen examples that begin with import *.. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You never call the `spiral` function you define; its code never runs. Where is the `circle` call defined?

Comment: t.penup()
t.goto(200, -50)
t.pendown()
t.circle(40, steps=40) this would make a circle

Comment: ... What happens when you try calling your `spiral()` function?'

Answer (score 1):

You're trying too hard -- the problem is simpler than you're making it:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from itertools import cycle

ANGLE = 8

colors = ["orange", "yellow", "tan", "pink", "coral"]

def spiral(turtle, radius, color_names):
    colors = cycle(color_names)

    for _ in range(360 // ANGLE):
        turtle.color(next(colors))
        turtle.circle(radius)
        turtle.left(ANGLE)

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.speed("fastest")

spiral(yertle, 50, colors)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want circles of radius 50 to pass through the origin, the *centers* of the required circles must be exactly 50 units away from the origin.

Now consider the definition of a circle. It is a collection of points (locus of a point is the correct terminology, but it doesn't matter), all of which are at a *fixed distance* (called the radius) from a *fixed point* (called the center). If you remember, we surmised that

> the *centers* of the required circles must be exactly 50 units away from the origin

Well, what do you know! These centers form a *circle* with *the origin* as the center, and a radius of *50 units*. We now know that we require circles of radius 50 units, each of whose centers lies on the *circle* with *radius 50 units* and *the origin as the center*.

What we have got to do now is *move* to a point on the circle with radius 50 units and the origin as the center, and *draw* a circle with radius 50 around that point. The point on the circle to move the turtle to can be found by rotating around the circle by 8 degrees (you can change this value) every time.

I hope that helps you out enough to implement this yourself. If not, take a look at @cdlane's answer.